# Faster way to do: sum(hypotenuse) / count

Tags: math

I have a very simple formula that adds the distances to pixels measured from the center (of a blob). Each distance is multiplied by a specific value (brightness of pixel).

```
for each pixel:
   distance += sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) * brightness
   sumBr += brightness

finally:
distance /= sumBr
```

dx and dy can be non integral, as they are deltas from the center calculated with the brightness (each pixel x * brightness and y * brightness, divided by sum of brightness).

This gives me an accurate reading of the average distance (of the blob).

This all works fine, but at times the Math.sqrt() function is taking a lot of processing time, which I figure might be unnecessary.

This problem is probably simple, but I haven't succeeded yet at solving it.

**Added: One attempt**

```
float sumX = 0f;
float sumY = 0f;
float sumBr = 0f;

for pixels:
   sumX += Math.abs(dx) * brightness
   sumY += Math.abs(dy) * brightness
   sumBr += brightness;

finally:
sumX /= sumBr;
sumY /= sumBr;
float distance = Math.sqrt(sumX * sumX + sumY * sumY);
```

This attempt gives my a deviation of ~10%. With sqrt in loop: 0.342, 0.101 and  without: 0.319, 0.093. I'm left wondering which is more accurate, as the last one seems less likely to have trouble with precision loss. I guess I'll have to write a test to find out, but I'm short on time to work on it at the moment unfortunately.

*Edit:* After some thinking, the above would never work.

Comment: It's pseudocode actually. I don't mind what language the answer is in. My problem is that the square root function is taking up too much time. It's probably everywhere (not just Java as in my case).

Comment: I removed the tag. You guys are quick.

Comment: Should that code be indented under the loop? Now it looks pythonic

Comment: Square root taking too long? Are you using later than Java 8 update 25? What makes you think it's taking too much time?

Comment: @Rogue I'm watching time spent with a profiler. Square root can take 15% of cpu time. I was thinking it might not be needed to do this way at all and save that time.

Comment: Possible overflows aside, calculate the square of the distance in the loop `d2 += (dx * dx + dy * dy) * brightness * brightness` then take the square root at the end `distance = sqrt(d2) / sumBR`.

Comment: Have you thought instead to not sqrt the values, and perhaps operate off the squared hypotenuses (aka do you need exact distance, or relative distances to other values e.g. in finding the "closest path")

Comment: Does the processing time actually matter?

Comment: **dxiv:** That doesn't seem to give accurate results for me. I'll check if I'm doing something wrong. **Rogue:** I need the exact distance to do real world distance calculation, so I can't do with a squared result. **Andrew Morton:** The application is computer vision, so less time spent means I have more time for other stuff.

Comment: How big is the image? If it's not too big and you're doing this a lot, you could build a lookup table of `(dx,dy) -> distance` up front. And you could shrink the table by noting that `(dx,dy)` == `(dy,dx)` == `(-dx,dy)` etc.

Comment: actually, even if you don't use a lookup table, you can divide the number of sqrts by 8 by doing (+/-dx, +/-dy) and (+/-dy, +/-dx) all at the same time

Comment: @CupawnTae I really like that solution and I will think about that. Only problem I foresee is that I am dealing with subpixel information (the brightness) which might be problematic/complicated with a lookup table.

Comment: Are you saying that dx and dy can be non-integral?

Comment: @CupawnTae This is not shown, but dx and dy are floats, because the center is computed with an average using the brightness. The dx and dy can be non integral.

Comment: Are you iterating over every pixel in a range? Or do you have a list of pixels with x,y stored?

Comment: @NicoSchertler You are right of course, and I removed that last comment. The original idea was that the square-root of the sum *varies* the same way (in a sense) with the sum of square-roots, so it could be used in certain cases such as minimization. But the OP later clarified that he needed the actual distance for other purposes, so that idea falls.